# Play WebSocket client for load testing another play websocket server app

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, scalatest

We have an existing play server app to which mobile clients talk via web sockets (two way communication). Now as part of load testing we need to simulate hundreds of client requests to the server.

I was thinking to write a separate play client (faceless) app and somehow in a loop make 100s of requests to a server app? Given that I am new to web sockets, does this approach sound reasonable?

Also what is the best way to write a faceless web socket client that makes web socket requests to a web socket server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to properly validate the performance of your application, it is very important to :
simulate the behavior of real users by simulating real "websocket" connections
 - reproduce a realistic end-user journey on the application utilizing the websocket channel
 It's important to generate the proper user workflow ( actions done by a user when receiving a websocket message). For example in a betting application users interact with the applicaiton depending on the messages received by the browser.

To be able to generate a realistic load test, I would recommend to use a real loadtesting software supporting Websocket. It will allow you to generate Different kind of users, with different kind of network, different kind of browsers....etc
What is the framework use by your applicaiton? Depending on the framework i could recommend the proper tool for you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a difference between hundreds of clients and hundreds of requests from the same client.
When you have hundreds of clients, the requests can come in **at the same time**.
When you only have one client, requests will mostly come in **sequentially** (depending on using one or multiple threads).

When you only have one client, you can perfectly send requests using a loop. What you will actually measure here is the processing latency of the server.

When you want to simulate multiple clients, this is a bit more difficult. If you simulate them from one machine, the requests are pipelined through the network card and hence the requests are not really send in parallel. Also, you are limited by the bandwidth of the machine. Suppose the server has a 1Gb connection and your test machine has a 1Gb connection, then you can never *overload* the bandwidth of the server. If your clients are supposed to have a limited bandwidth like 50Mb, then you can run 20 clients (not taking into account the serialisation that happens through the network card).
In theory, you should use as many machines as the number of clients you want to test.  In reality, you would use a number of machines each running a limited number of clients.

Regarding a headless test application, you could use a headless browser testing framework like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).

Comment: parallel or not is not an issue since motto of this test is to see how server holds up against 100s of websocket connections by different clients. can this be achieved/simulated by wiring a separate test play app to generate new connection requests without having multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple websocket client using Node.js.
If the server is open and ready to accept the request then you can fire the requests as written below,

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

 const url = ws://localhost:9000/ws
 const connection = new WebSocket(url)

 connection.onopen = () => {
    for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
        connection.send('hello')
    }
 }

 connection.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log(event.data)
 }

 connection.onerror = (error) => {
    console.log(`WebSocket error: ${error}`)
 }
```